# Table header fixed, scrollable body horizontal and vertical, variable cell width

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollable

I realize this question has been asked quite a bit on Stack Overflow; however, after looking through a number of them, I believe my question has one more requirement. I want to transform a regular html table, into a table that can be scrolled both vertically and horizontally, while the header is fixed. The table in my project is dynamically generated, so the cell width can't be fix.

Problems:

- when scrolling left and right, the table scrolls, but the header is cut off
- header and body cell width doesn't fit

Here is a JSFiddle to show you my problem

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nps0x7zj/44/)

Table example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="vehicleTable" class="table pointer hover table-striped table-bordered" role="grid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Size</th> 
        <th>Mass</th>
        <th>Eyecolor</th>
        <th>Style</th> 
        <th>Shoe</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
        <th>Social Media</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Jill</td>
         <td>Smith</td> 
         <td>50</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.60</td> 
         <td>60</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>New Balance</td>
         <td>Football</td> 
         <td>Facebook</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Anthony</td>
         <td>Meyer</td> 
         <td>34</td>
         <td>Male</td>
         <td>1.84</td> 
         <td>88</td>
         <td>Blue</td>
         <td>Elegant</td> 
         <td>All stars</td>
         <td>Golf</td> 
         <td>Facebook</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Eve</td>
         <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td>94</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.58</td> 
         <td>55</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>Adidas</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jill</td>
         <td>Smith</td> 
         <td>50</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.60</td> 
         <td>60</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>New Balance</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Anthony</td>
         <td>Meyer</td> 
         <td>34</td>
         <td>Male</td>
         <td>1.84</td> 
         <td>88</td>
         <td>Blue</td>
         <td>Elegant</td> 
         <td>All stars</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Eve</td>
         <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td>94</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.58</td> 
         <td>55</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>Adidas</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Anthony</td>
         <td>Meyer</td> 
         <td>34</td>
         <td>Male</td>
         <td>1.84</td> 
         <td>88</td>
         <td>Blue</td>
         <td>Elegant</td> 
         <td>All stars</td>
         <td>Golf</td> 
         <td>Facebook</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Eve</td>
         <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td>94</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.58</td> 
         <td>55</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>Adidas</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jill</td>
         <td>Smith</td> 
         <td>50</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.60</td> 
         <td>60</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>New Balance</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Anthony</td>
         <td>Meyer</td> 
         <td>34</td>
         <td>Male</td>
         <td>1.84</td> 
         <td>88</td>
         <td>Blue</td>
         <td>Elegant</td> 
         <td>All stars</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Eve</td>
         <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td>94</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.58</td> 
         <td>55</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>Adidas</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jill</td>
         <td>Smith</td> 
         <td>50</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.60</td> 
         <td>60</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>New Balance</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Anthony</td>
         <td>Meyer</td> 
         <td>34</td>
         <td>Male</td>
         <td>1.84</td> 
         <td>88</td>
         <td>Blue</td>
         <td>Elegant</td> 
         <td>All stars</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Eve</td>
         <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td>94</td>
         <td>Female</td>
         <td>1.58</td> 
         <td>55</td>
         <td>Green</td>
         <td>Cool</td> 
         <td>Adidas</td>
         <td>Chess</td>
         <td>Instagram</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table#vehicleTable {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table#vehicleTable thead {
    position: relative;
    display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  width: inherit;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
table#vehicleTable tbody {
    position: relative;
    display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
    width: inherit;
    max-height: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.table-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table#vehicleTable td, table#vehicleTable thead th {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('tbody').scroll(function (e) { 
            $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft());
            $('thead th div:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
            $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to handle the possibility of longer columns, as I didn't notice that prerequisite**

Interesting problem!

You can achieve what you want with less `CSS` <strike>and no `jQuery`, if you are happy to set a fixed width for the columns:</strike>

If you ensure that your CSS is set so that the default column width is as long as is necessary for any table headers, then this solution should work:

**CSS**

```
table#vehicleTable {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
table#vehicleTable thead {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
table#vehicleTable tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 345px; /*allowing for scrollbar and th height */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table#vehicleTable td, table#vehicleTable th  {
  min-width: 100px; /*suitable width for all column headers in the example*/
}

/*Added this just to handle the 2nd column, which needs to be smaller, as per comments */

table#vehicleTable td:nth-of-type(2), table#vehicleTable th:nth-of-type(2) {
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $i = 0;
    $("#vehicleTable tbody tr:first-of-type td").each(function()
  {
    $i++;
    width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $("#vehicleTable thead th:nth-of-type(" +$i+")").css({"min-width": width+"px"});
  });
});
```

This will loop through the first `row` of `tbody`, and get the respective widths for each column.  If you don't set a `min-width` on them first, then any columns with data that is shorter than the column header will result in that column shrinking, while the header itself will still expand to fit its own content.

Also updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nps0x7zj/108/)

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful, but i've got an other problem. My second field in the table is just one "file" icon, and 
the width is too big for that icon. Do you have any idea to resize the siz of this cell?

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nps0x7zj/110/#&togetherjs=P3ELjUzmFJ

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  I've updated my answer with some extra css to handle the 2nd column.
You could probably make life easier if you can add classes to your columns, but it depends on the level of control you have over the output.